# In wso2 ESB property mediator what is the property RESPONSE means

Tags: wso2, wso2-esb

In WSO2 ESB what does the property mediator with name RESPONSE and value true will do:

```
<property name="RESPONSE" scope="default" value="true"/>
```

And what is sequential mediation,payload preserve,continue parent means in iterator mediator

Comment: The RESPONSE property dates from before the <respond/> mediator.  name="RESPONSE" value="true"> + <send/> is exactly the same as the <respond/> mediator, it is just legacy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once [RESPONSE](https://docs.wso2.com/display/EI611/Generic+Properties#GenericProperties-RESPONSE) property is set to 'true' on a message, the ESB will start treating it as a response message. It is generally used to route a request message back to its source as the response.If you configure a send mediator after a RESPONSE property ESB will respond to the client back (same as respond mediator). Instead of respond property and send mediator you can replace those with respond mediator.